# Hard code HTML5 application into Qt Webview

Tags: c++, html, qt, qwebview

Manually hard coding html and image files using `setHtml` and `setContent` is tedious. Is there a way to automate this? I don't want the Qt 5.2 application to load external files.

Example:

```
QString content = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\"><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"><title>Hello World</title></head><html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>";
QWebView view;
view.show();
view.setHtml(content,QUrl("index.html"));
```

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/resources.html

Comment: @Mat `setContent` requires QByteArray. Does the resource system provide the files in QByteArray format?

Comment: If you do not want to load external files, how exactly would you like to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add your html and image files to a qrc (a Qt resource), and thus compile them into the app. Then you can use QWebView's load method to load the resource like this:

```
QWebView view;
view.load(QUrl(":/myIndex.html");
```

You can read more about resources [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/resources.html).